# Create a master table component and add child columns dynamically in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Good morning everyone !

So have to create an application that displays many tables that all look the same (except their columns of course and the objects inside).

I have a master table component which can be summarized by:

```
<master-table>
  <!-- here I define the master table style, pagination, etc etc 
       which is the same everywhere -->
</master-table>
```

In the master table component TS file I have basically options that are relevant for every page where this kind of table should be displayed, such as filterDate, clearSelection etc etc etc nothing very special.

The point is, I don't want to repeat this code every where because it is not necessary, so my idea was to create several component that would extend the master table component.

It works fine for the typescript values, but I am stuck with the HTML.

In my master table HTML I would like at some point some kind of placeholder something like this:

```
<master-table>
  <standard-for-all-table></standard-for-all-table>

  <!-- insert here child columns -->
</master-table>
```

In the components that extends my master table I was imagining then something like:

```
<!-- child component -->
<master-table></master-table>
<child-column>column definition</child-column>
```

Doing this would allow me to define only the columns in the child components HTML and they would be added automatically to the parent HTML at runtime...

Any idea how to do this ?

Cheers and thanks !

Comment: basically you need a `child` component inside a more generic `parent` component?

Comment: I think you want to abstract the code as much as possible. So one option would be to create more different `child-column` components with many logic you want, and add it to the parent `master-table` based on your conditions. And you have to put your `child-column` component reference tag inside the html of the `master-table` component

Comment: If you want only one `<child-column>` inside one `<master-table>` and the child dynamically changes content based on condition you have to create a shared service (`provider)` between parent and child

Comment: I basically have let say a table, and this table has a TS and an HTML associated to it, then I have children that extend this table, for instance clients, users, houses etc. All of those would use that mother table and just add their own column, so I don't have to reuse the filter logic and add/remove logic etc etc which is already done in the mother. So at the end I would have many child columns depending on the child objects being displayed (either being clients, customers, whatever)

Comment: I have those providers already and the different children, now I would like for the child to use the parent HTML and fill it up with the missing columns that's the last step :) 
I don't want to have all the possible columns in my master table as I don't think it is the way to go, I could of course do that and do some ngSwitch and problem solved but honesty I don't like that approach... (maybe I am completely wrong)

Comment: Ok now i've undestand your issue. So i'll write my answer for you. In short my idea w'll be to create a generic `<child-column>` component and create in it's html structure all possible `td` columns you could use, inject in it the data based on your need with the Angular expression `{{data.variable}}` and hide the columns you don't need with `*ngIf="variable"`

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try to go that way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to create your main `master-table` component and your generic list `chid-column` component and insert it in your parent `html` template structure.

> I've edit the final part hope in a better understanding way...

Then you can structure your child component to contain all the properties you need and thanks to `*ngIf` show only the properties you return from your provider methods i.e. `getClients()`, `getUsers()`, `getHouses()`, also thanks to the `@Input` decorator you can inject this data directly from the parent to the child and create many components you want with just a change of the data.

So in your parent you can have something like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { MY_DATA_FROMP_ROVIDER } from './mydata/provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'master-table',
  template: `
    <ul>
     <child-column *ngFor="let item of items"
      [item]="item">
     </app-hero-child>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class MasterTableComponent {
  items:any

  constructor(public data: MYDATAFROMPROVIDER) {
      this.items = MYDATAFROMPROVIDER.myGetMethod();
}
```

And in your child

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { INTERFACE } from './mydata/interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-column',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="item.id">{{item.id}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="item.name">{{item.name}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="item.address">{{item.address}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="item.phone">{{item.phone}}</div>
  `
})
export class ChildColumnComponent {
  @Input() item: INTERFACE;
}
```

If you want to go deeper: [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score -1):

This guide is from official angular page [Here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)
Here is the [live sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bqrydkmlkxg) of it

Not sure if these links could help.
But I actually worked on a project where we want to dynamically loading Child component into a Grid(Parent component).
And later on we can pass any component with different view inside the Grid
Guess that pretty close to your goal.